# Options for Multiplayer games graphics running on the server

Tags: graphics, multiplayer, dedicated-server, unreal-engine5

What options are there to run a simple multiplayer game (like 10 players) but with high end graphics via the server. Is it possible and realistic?

As I understand it a dedicated server don't take care of the graphics? Does the graphics always need to be on the client/local side?
Can you setup a dedicated server with graphics cards?

If possible, would it totally drain the internet connection, would the screen be lacking?
Alternative can it work in a lan setup?

If a game usually need a high end graphics card, would it then on the server need 10x graphics cards for 10 players?

Answer (score 0):

Graphics card is used to give Visual effect in order to make game more attractive to players. But server just need to do the logic thing, there is no need to have any graphics card.